# Slider cropping images instead of resizing them

Tags: html, css, resize, slider, crop

This is the CSS for Nivo Slider that my theme has:

```
*Nivo Slider*/
#zn_nivo {position:relative; height:550px; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.slide_wrap{width:100%; margin:0 auto; height:550px; overflow:hidden;}
.nivoSlider {position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;overflow: hidden;}
.nivoSlider img {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;max-width:none;}
.nivo-main-image {display: block !important;position: relative !important; width: 100% !important;height:auto !important;}
/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;z-index:6;display:none;background:white; filter:alpha(opacity=0); opacity:0;}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {display:block;position:absolute;z-index:5;height:100%;top:0;}
.nivo-box {display:block;position:absolute;z-index:5;overflow:hidden;}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }
```

However when I insert an image into the slide, the image doesn't get resized properly and shows up differently on different monitors which is something I do not want. What I mean is shown on these two pictures, you can see an example of a `4:3 1280*1024` display and `16:9 1920*1080` and the 16:9 one gets cropped.

16:9 [image: 16:9]
4:3 [image: 4:3]

I do not want the picture to be cropped at all, I want the slides to include 100% of the picture and not crop it. I've tried modifying the `.nivoSlider img` by changing the `max-width` to `100%` and adding `max-height:100%`, but I got really weird results which were partly alright, but there were 2 pictures showing up occasionally and I'm not exactly sure as to why that happened. Somebody please help me??

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem about "how to resize image automatically using nivo slider" and i have been solve the problem, i do some modification in "jquery.nivo.slider.js" file, and the image will resize automatically, here is an [example](http://forkiki.com/slide/index.html), you can download it [here](http://netra-knowledge.com/slidesample.zip) , i hope it can be useful for you and for other, thank you